# How do I avoid this repetitive code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bunch of subroutines for a worksheet that all start and end exactly the same way. They all basically loop through every row in the table and perform some unique operation to each individual row. I do not want them all to run every time, instead I want to be able to call them individually.

Here's what the actual code looks like:

```
Sub randomSub()
    Dim finalRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    finalRow = Sheet.Cells(Rows.count, Column).End(xlUp).row

    With Sheet2
        For i = 3 To finalRow
            ' Do some random operations here
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Setting the code up to loop through every row is not hard but after repeating it across 4 or 5 different subs I imagine there is a better way.

So I guess my question is this: Is there a best practice for avoiding writing a loop set-up like this over and over for every new sub I make?

EDIT: Here's some examples of the type of operations I'm doing, and would normally replace the `' Do random operations here`

```
Sub moveToFront()
    Dim stringHolder() As String

    stringHolder = Split(Sheet2.Cells(i, 11), "; ")
    If stringHolder(1) = "" Then
        .Cells(i, 11) = stringHolder(0)
    Else
        .Cells(i, 11) = stringHolder(1) & "; " & stringHolder(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

And another

```
Sub fillInTotals()
    If .Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
        .Cells(i, 1) = "='EUS Graph'!$C$" & _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 3), Sheet4.Range("$A:$A"), 0)
    Else
        .Cells(i, 1) = "='EUS Graph'!$C$"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Protip: make an account and post your **actual, working code** in full context on [codereview.se], make the title say *what problem your code is solving*, explain reviewers what the code is doing and why, and you'll get feedback and suggestions about all aspects of the code, *including* ways to extract methods and parameterize your procedural code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a generalized user-defined function and place it where all macros have access to it, either the `ThisWorkbook` section or a standard module:

```
Public Function randomSub(SheetName As String, ColumnLetter As String, _
                          OperationType As String)
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, finalRow As Long
    Dim stringHolder() As String

    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    With wsh
        finalRow = wsh.Cells(wsh.Rows.Count, ColumnLetter).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 3 To finalRow                              
             Select Case OperationType

                 Case "MoveToFront"
                    stringHolder = Split(Sheet2.Cells(i, 11), "; ")
                    If stringHolder(1) = "" Then
                        .Cells(i, 11) = stringHolder(0)
                    Else
                        .Cells(i, 11) = stringHolder(1) & "; " & stringHolder(0)
                    End If

                 Case  "fillInTotals"
                    If .Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
                            .Cells(i, 1) = "='EUS Graph'!$C$" & _
                                     Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 3), _
                                     Sheet4.Range("$A:$A"), 0)
                    Else
                            .Cells(i, 1) = "='EUS Graph'!$C$"
                    End If

             End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Then, call the function as needed, passing required parameters:

```
Call randomSub(ActiveSheet.Name, "A", "MoveToFront")
```

Comment: How would I go about changing the `random operations` though? I don't have a problem generalizing to use on other sheets or workbooks. It's the fact that I have to re-write this code for each `random operation` that I want to do

Comment: Structurally, do the random operations do the same thing like pass a formula/value to each cell which you can pass a parameter? Does code differ by grouping/category which you can add conditionals in general function. Please post more detail.

Comment: I included some examples of what I'm trying to do in my edit

Comment: See edit passing in an *OperationType* parameter that will condition the `for` loop operation using `Select...Case` logic. You may want to nest for/loops within the Cases.

Comment: Ok, that's what my original plan was. I was just wondering if looping through that `Select...Case` logic was the most efficient way to do that.

Comment: As mentioned, try reversing by nesting for/loop inside the case blocks so you do not need to check iteratively. Check performance of either.